# How can I manage apps with File Sharing within iOS (without using computer)?

Tags: ios, folders, copy-paste, file-sharing, file-transfer

I want to know if I can manage (copy MEDIA (music or video) from it   and   paste MEDIA to it) the File Sharing folder of iOS apps using iOS devices (iPhone, iPad ...) without plugging the device to a computer. **AND WITHOUT JAILBREAK**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What does "file sharing folder of iOS" look like. Can you perhaps elaborate on one app and a specific version of iOS that you are trying to configure/use? 9Also - what is being copied from and pasting to - entire document/files or text snippets or images? - some might be easier to accomplish than others.)

Answer (score -2):

If you have already jailbreaked, then you can use iFile. If not, sorry I don't know either.

Comment: The author clearly stated jailbreak was out of the question.